# MFMessageComposeViewController wrong focuse on the field

Tags: ios, ios8, uitextview

I was implementing possibility to invite friends via SMS and small problem occur. Problem is connected with wrong focus on the field.

Image below describe problem :

[image: Image from iphone]

And as it is possible to see focus is before word "кому:" but not after.

So could some one help me please to understand how it is possible to set proper focus in the `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

Code that show SMS view is below:

```
if ([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
{
            MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
            [messageController setBody:@"I'm on Memry, come join me! =) \n https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/memry/id735465896?mt=8"];
            messageController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{
                                                                   NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor],
                                                                   };
            messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:messageController animated:NO completion:nil];
            [messageController release];
        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Memry"
                                                            message:@"Your device does not support SMS"
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alert show];
            [alert release];
}
```

Comment: What version of iOS are you using?

Comment: I'm unable to recreate this on my device. When I test focus is set before the word "To:", "Komy:" in your case, for a split second before it resets it's focus to outside, where it should be. The only difference is I'm using ARC. Perhaps your release statements are being called too soon?

Comment: Thx for you point Daniel but this problem is not connected with ARC.

Answer (score 1):

```
    MFMessageComposeViewController *messageController = [[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [messageController setRecipients:@[@"+86 15011582532"]];
    [messageController setBody:@"I'm on Memry, come join me! =) \n https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/memry/id735465896?mt=8"];
    messageController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{
                                                            NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor],
                                                            };
    messageController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
    [self.view.window.rootViewController presentViewController:messageController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

add some default value in recipients.

Comment: Yes i already use this trick but is seems to me not so perfect solution.